# How do i delete the header?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm trying to delete this grey rectangle saying "Progetto" on the device screen , but i don't know how to do it. I didn't add it , it was already in my project. Does anyone know how to do it? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: i think...you can't delete it...but hide...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem myself. Here is how i did it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

On AndroidManifest.xml you need to write for all activities:

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Answer (score 0):

Set it in your app's manifest file by adding android:theme property in the application tag. Example:

```
<application
    android:allowClearUserData="false"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".AnotherActivity" />
</application>
```